# jQuery addClass() not working when also using attr("href", something)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create a link (in form of a Bootstrap button) that works only on the second click; on the first click it is supposed to change its appearance a bit. For this I use `.addClass(newClass)`, `.removeClass(oldClass)`, and then `attr("href", newUrl)`.

*(Edit)* To clarify: In the beginning, the link (anchor) has "#" as its `href` target, and an onlick handler. That handler, when executed on the first click, will remove itself from the anchor, and instead set the desired target URL in the `href`attribute. That is supposed to cause the link to only redirect to its target URL on the *second* click.)

This almost works, but only if I omit the `attr()` setting. When it is there, the class reverts to the old class of the link as soon as the script exits. When I step through it in the debugger, the link briefly changes its appearance as expected, but changes back when the event handler exits.

This is the HTML code:

```
<a id="twoclick-vjffkrzw" onclick="enabletwoclickbutton('twoclick-vjffkrzw', 
'http://localhost/something.php?cmd=admin&amp;func=userdetail&amp;pk=53&amp;action=removerole&amp;rolepk=1')"
class="btn btn-xs btn-warning" href="#">Remove this</a>
```

The script:

```
function enabletwoclickbutton(btn_id, url) {
    var whichbtn = '#' + btn_id;
    var btn = $(whichbtn);
    if (btn.hasClass("btn-warning")) {
        btn.off("click");
        btn.attr("href", url);
        btn.removeClass('btn-warning');
        btn.addClass('btn-danger');

    } else {
        console.log("Hey, this shouldnt happen.");
    }

}
```

I'm not very experienced in JS and jQuery, so it's quite possible that this is a stupid mistake on my side, but I just can't see it.

Comment: Cancel the click action

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `e.preventDefault()` to avoid the default behavior of anchor.

Your way **(however I recommend you to go with one below for readability and easy to modify later.)**

**html**

```
<a id="twoclick-vjffkrzw" onclick="enabletwoclickbutton(event,'twoclick-vjffkrzw', 'http://localhost/something.php?cmd=admin&amp;func=userdetail&amp;pk=53&amp;action=removerole&amp;rolepk=1')" class="btn btn-xs btn-warning" href="#">Remove this</a>
```

**js**

```
 function enabletwoclickbutton(e,btn_id, url) {
    var whichbtn = '#' + btn_id;
    var btn = $(whichbtn);
    if (btn.hasClass("btn-warning")) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //btn.off("click");
        btn.attr("href", url);
        btn.removeClass('btn-warning')
           .addClass('btn-danger');

    } else {
        console.log("Hey, this shouldnt happen.");
    }

}
```

**Recommended**

Do not mix your javascript and html which is very hard to read as you can see in your code. You can write the entire code in javascript only

eg.

```js
$('#twoclick-vjffkrzw').click(function(e){
    var btn = $(this);
    if (btn.hasClass("btn-warning")) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //btn.off("click");
        btn.attr("href", 'http://localhost/something.php?cmd=admin&amp;func=userdetail&amp;pk=53&amp;action=removerole&amp;rolepk=1');
        btn.removeClass('btn-warning');
        btn.addClass('btn-danger');

    } else {
        console.log("Hey, this shouldnt happen.");
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="twoclick-vjffkrzw" class="btn btn-xs btn-warning" href="#">Remove this</a>
```

Comment: But on second click, the event would still be prevented

Comment: Opps the OP edited the question. In that case move the `preventDefault()` inside the if condition... :) :).. updated already anyways Thanks @A.Wolff

Comment: @ᴀʀᴛᴜʀғɪʟɪᴘɪᴀᴋ yes make sense!! updated Thanks :)... removed the `.off`.  Feel free and update it .

Answer (score 2):

First add `return false;` after the `onclick` function call to stop the default redirect. Then in your function you can set the `onclick` to `null` so that it isn't called a second time.

```js
function enabletwoclickbutton(btn_id, url) {
  var whichbtn = '#' + btn_id;
  var btn = $(whichbtn);
  if (btn.hasClass("btn-warning")) {
    btn.off("click");
    btn.attr("href", url);
    btn.removeClass('btn-warning');
    btn.addClass('btn-danger');
    btn.attr('onclick', null);
  } else {
    console.log("Hey, this shouldnt happen.");
  }

}
```

```css
.btn-warning {
  color: orange;
}
.btn-danger {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="twoclick-vjffkrzw" onclick="enabletwoclickbutton('twoclick-vjffkrzw', 
'http://localhost/something.php?cmd=admin&amp;func=userdetail&amp;pk=53&amp;action=removerole&amp;rolepk=1');return false;" class="btn btn-xs btn-warning" href="#">Remove this</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to check if it is the first time you click the button. to do this you can use a variable . check the code below

```
var clk=0;
function enabletwoclickbutton(btn_id, url) {
if(clk==0){
 clk++;
}else{
clk=0;
var whichbtn = '#' + btn_id;
    var btn = $(whichbtn);
    if (btn.hasClass("btn-warning")) {
        btn.off("click");
        btn.attr("href", url);
        btn.removeClass('btn-warning');
        btn.addClass('btn-danger');

    } else {
        console.log("Hey, this shouldnt happen.");
    }
}
```

check [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q2a9kjf9/)

Comment: Not necessary; that is done by the class-checking. On the second click, the link doesn't have the `btn-warning` class any more.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `data` attribute to store `url` value (added `my-btn` class for clarity)

```
<a data-action="http://localhost/something.php?cmd=admin&amp;func=userdetail&amp;pk=53&amp;action=removerole&amp;rolepk=1" class="btn btn-xs btn-warning my-btn" href="#">Remove this</a>
```

Then set `click` function with jQuery instead of using `onClick` attribute ([as it's not good practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871640/why-is-using-onclick-in-html-a-bad-practice)):

```
$('.my-btn').click(function(event){
    // prevent default click action:
    event.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).hasClass("btn-warning")) {
        $(this).removeClass('btn-warning').addClass('btn-danger');
    }else{
        // go to url on a second click:
        location.href = $(this).data("action");
    }
});
```

---

**EDIT** (*@A.Wolff* comment)
BTW.: Checking the existence of `btn-warning` class is actually pointless. The `click` event won't be handled at the second click anyway...

```
$('.my-btn').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).removeClass('btn-warning').addClass('btn-danger')
           .off('click').attr('href', $(this).data("action"));
});
```

Comment: This won't handle all specific cases of anchor click behaviour, like holding the ctrl key to open it in new tab/window. This could or not matter

Answer (score 0):

With input from the various answers, I was able to find out what was happening.

Apparently the changed `href` will be executed only *after* the the event handler exits. Since in my configuration by chnce it redirected to the same page, the page was actually reloaded, that's why the button/link got its original appearance back and that tricked me into believing that the `attr()` setting didn't work right.

The key was to simply call `event.preventDefault()` before setting the new URL.

Some of you recommended (directly or indirectly) to generate the button click handler in JS directly. I don't think this would make the code better readable (the only thing that made the HTML unreadable is the long URL.) As the HTML is generated dynamically, this wouldn't be a practical solution anyway.

So, the finalized code looks like this:

```
function enabletwoclickbutton(e, btn_id, url) {
    var whichbtn = '#' + btn_id;
    var btn = $(whichbtn);
    if (btn.hasClass("btn-warning")) {
        e.preventDefault();
        btn.off("click");
        btn.attr("href", url);
        btn.removeClass('btn-warning');
        btn.addClass('btn-danger');
    } else {
        console.log("Hey, this shouldnt happen.");
    }

}
```

Now it works as exected.